# Bad values for joystick input in unity 5

Tags: unity-game-engine, joystick

I have a "noname" USB joystick and I try to use it in a Unity project.
The buttons are working fine, but I have troubles with axis values.

According to Unity5 documention, for each axis, I should get values :

- -1.0 when the axis is pushed to the "minimum" (left for X axis or down for Y axis)
- 0.0 when the axis is at center
- +1.0 when the axis is pushed to the "maximum" (right for X axis or up for Y axis)

But I get :

- -1.0 when the axis is at center
- 0.0 when the axis is halfway between center and maximum
- +1.0 when the axis is pushed to the "maximum" (right for X axis or up for Y
- +1.0 if the axis is pushed at any position below center

I really don't understand why I get these values :

- when I display the windows joystick calibration UI (run "joy.cpl") the joystick is working fine.
- when I use an existent game, the joystick is working fine
- I tried some joystick test programs found on the internet, each time the joystick is working fine
- I tried some HTML5 joystick test sites, each time the joystick is working fine

But I can't believe there is such a problem in Unity5, so it must be in my code...

Here is a simple test code I use in Unity to display values :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class JoystickTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float Position           = 0.0f;

    void Update()
    {
        float value = Input.GetAxis("Player 1");
        Position = value;
    }
}
```

And the Unity input manager is configured as follow :

[image]

I've tried to play with input manager settings, with windows joystick settings, with my code... no way, the result is still the same : work in any application except in my Unity test project...

On Google, I've found some post about the same problem, but no solution...

Any help will be really appreciated !

Thanks

Comment: Where is the second axis for up&down? Shouldn you use Horizontal and Vertical?

Comment: GetAxisRaw returns the same, If I play with sensivity, it's the same, and there is no second axis in this example to keep it as simple as possible. All looks like Unity is messing up my joystick inputs, but I can't believe it, I must do something wrong.